# Satisfy create, update and delete operations in one rest API request

Tags: mongodb, rest, backend, api-design

I have many thoughts about how to design an API, do not know exactly what is the best practice to follow and would need a bit of help picking the correct approach.

Suppose that in a Mongo database there is a collection `shop` with the following schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  products: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId,
      name: String,
      price: Number,
      status: String // 'active' | 'inactive' | 'soft_deleted',
    }
  ]
}
```

There is already a `/shop` API and the need is to create another one (maybe `/shop/:shopId/products`) that will handle the `create`, `update`, `delete`, `get` operations of `products` array. That can be easily made following the RESTful guidelines.

But what if we want the `CUD` operations to be done in one request?

Suppose that, in the client (frontend application), the user can create, delete and update products (not `soft_deleted` ones) and THEN click a button save and the backend application will apply these operations in the database. The thing is that these operations will not be done one by one because the user will click save when he has finished with all the changes(`CUD`) he wants to make.

I did a little bit of digging, and it seems this API cannot follow the REST guidelines. I came up with the following solutions:

1. Make the API RESTful and the client will make many requests to the `/shop/:shopId/products` for the `CUD` operations. I've concluded that this is not ideal, considering that there will be many requests and there will some overhead.
2. Somehow, use the `PATCH` method to include all operations in the body as JSON. That also does not seems right, considering that this is not REST and PATCH should be used for updating fields and deleting fields for one resource (and also for not updating the whole document). One request will be made
3. Use PUT and the client will send the whole array (without `soft_deleted` ones) and the backend will handle the different operations somehow and make different queries. One request will be made.
4. Create another endpoint `shop/:shopId/products/batch` with method `POST` and do one request. Example request:

```
[
  { op: "create", name: "test", price: 2, status: 'active' }
  { op: "delete", id: "id-to-be-deleted" }
  { op: "update", id: "id-of-product-to-be-update", price: 5 }
  { op: "update", id: "id-of-product-to-be-update", name: "newName", price: 6, status: 'inactive' }
]
```

With some transformation in the backend, three queries would be made.

I would like to ask, what is the recommended way to tackle this and what would be the best in terms of architecture and design. My goal was to make this API RESTful but I am not sure if that's doable. Some of the above solutions I mentioned, I understand that they are not RESTful but considering the requirements, what would be the best approach?